# Can you get basic GC stats in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I would like to have some long-running server applications periodically output general GC performance numbers in Java, something like the GC equivalent of Runtime.freeMemory(), etc.  Something like number of cycles done, average time, etc.

We have systems running on customer machines where there is a suspicion that misconfigured memory pools are causing excessive GC frequency and length - it occurs to me that it would be good in general to periodically report the basic GC activity.

Is there any platform independent way to do this?

**EDIT: I specifically want to output this data to the system log (the console), while running; this is not something I want to connect to the JVM for, as would be with JConsole or JVisualVM.**

Edit2: The MX bean looks like what I want - does anyone have a working code example which obtains one of these?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here's an example using `GarbageCollectorMXBean` to print out GC stats.  Presumably you would call this method periodically, e.g. scheduling using a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

```
public void printGCStats() {
    long totalGarbageCollections = 0;
    long garbageCollectionTime = 0;

    for(GarbageCollectorMXBean gc :
            ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()) {

        long count = gc.getCollectionCount();

        if(count >= 0) {
            totalGarbageCollections += count;
        }

        long time = gc.getCollectionTime();

        if(time >= 0) {
            garbageCollectionTime += time;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Total Garbage Collections: "
        + totalGarbageCollections);
    System.out.println("Total Garbage Collection Time (ms): "
        + garbageCollectionTime);
}
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks Greg. I already have a periodic monitor that prints memory usage and optionally threads.  This fits in nicely with that.

Comment: PS: Can't vote for another 46 minutes; will return and upvote this then.

Comment: Does `getCollectionCount()` return the count since the last time it was called, or the total count all time?

Comment: Testing has shown me that the count returned by `getCollectionCount()` is the total count since it has started, therefore the accumulator in this example will report a much higher total then has actually occurred.

Comment: @MikeRylander The accumulators in the sample code are intended to accumulate across multiple GarbageCollectorMXBean instances rather than multiple calls to the same instance.  Note that the accumulator variables are scoped to the method and are not static.

Comment: @GregCase Ah, that makes sense, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 16):

See [GarbageCollectorMXBean](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html).

Comment: Thanks, by the way Ran; would have accepted this too, if I could accept two answers.

Answer (score 12):

The JVM has a certain amount of garbage collector logging already built in, so depending on your requirements, you might not need a custom solution.

In Java 7, you can use `-XX:-PrintGC` and `-XX:-PrintGCDetails`; see [VM Debugging Options](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/vmoptions.jsp#DebuggingOptions).

In Java 8 to 10, use `-XX:+PrintGC` and `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` with a `+` instead of a `-` ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)).

In Java 11 or later, the -XX options [have been deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html#JSMIG-GUID-055EA9F4-835E-463F-B9E1-9081B3D9E55D) in favor of `-Xlog:gc`. See [Enabling Logging with the JVM Unified Logging Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-BE93ABDC-999C-4CB5-A88B-1994AAAC74D5) for more advanced options.

Comment: Good idea; but too verbose to be on always.  I want a periodic report, say every 5-60 minutes.

Comment: Then i think you'd have to write something else to capture the output and reformat/reoutput it at your times.

Comment: actually this worked for me: -XX:+PrintGC and -XX:+PrintGCDetails (with + sign)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off topic but you can hook up VisualVM and JConsole to running applications and see useful stats.

Comment: Refer to the bolded edit I wrote 13 hours before this answer was posted.

Comment: Apologies for that - sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees.