# Statistics of young and tenured generation memory in java

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

Is there any way in **Java** we can get access to the current state of memory like, how much of **tenured memory or young generation memory** is used currently by the JVM.

Doing a Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory(), totalMemory() is useful but I was wondering if there is any way to get the split of total memory.

Comment: Related: [Can you get basic GC stats in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/466878/102937)

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for the link. I searched on internet but didnt find this puppy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `-XX:-PrintGC` and `-XX:-PrintGCDetails;` 
Details for these can be found at following link
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

This link contains some more information related to stats 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html

Comment: thanks jabir. I also found similar link for Java 6 which may be useful http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html

Answer (score 1):

The **GC logging** is the best way to monitor Young and OldGen occupation.

And, `jstat` is another great way howto monitor the heap sizes, additionally to what GC logging will show you, jstat will show you the **Eden** and **Survivor** spaces occupation, try:

```
 jstat -gcutil -t <pid> <interval> <number_of_samples>
```

Answer (score 1):

Application Manager from Manage Engine does this job. Fantastic tool
http://www.manageengine.com/products/applications_manager/