# Why does my server initialize substantially slower in JUnit then when run stand-alone

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a server I want to do automated functional tests on.  It needs to initialize a few thousand total objects to build up it's in memory model, fetching data from config files, but this is still trivial for a computer and it's a near-instantaneous bootup when run from eclipse.

When I run the same program as part of a junit test the initialization phase takes 15 seconds or so instead of instantaneous speed of the stand-alone app.  Not that long, but if I plan to do many dozens of tests it will add up.

According to JVisualVM this time is spread out over a half dozen methods, no one method taking longer then 14% of CPU time (this is after I optimized away the method that was taking 50% of CPU).  All of the methods running are methods I expect to see running and seem taking a reasonable percentage of total CPU time; I can't compare it to the live server because the live server initializes so fast I can't start and stop JVisualVM fast enough to profile it.  It does seem as if the the init methods of all my objects may take longer, for instance one object uses 3% cpu for init, but has a self time of 000 ms and makes no other calls; but I don't know if that's a common result using JVisualVM?

Though it shouldn't matter I am doing one thing differently in my Junit vs running as a stand-alone app; I'm using a serverMock object (though it's hardly a mock ATM).  It extends my server object.  Right now the only reason to extend it is because the server's run method (which runs indefinitely waiting for incoming messages) is a protected method that is called by the main() method when server is run as a jar. My mock adds a method which will spawn a thread to run the server's run method since I have no other way of starting the method in a unit test.  However, the slow down is in the initialization of the server before it gets to the run method; so I don't think this is the cause of the slowdown?

Comment: Are you instrumenting the code for coverage reasons, or anything like that?

Comment: no, not yet.  I am writing the most basic of test suit currently.  So far I have two tests that do nothing but initalize server, ping it, and turn it off.  No code coverage or other behavior other then basic default junit behavior

Comment: And is this running under a debugger? (I'm not familiar with JVisualVM, but if you haven't tried running the tests under a "regular" JVM, that should be your first port of call.)

Comment: Are you using the same vmargs? And have you considered using Hudson/Jenkins to start the tests automatically on checkins?

Comment: I ran JVisualVm against a version of the code in debugger, so I could target only the part of the init that was taking unusually long.  However, I have run the tests outside of debugger and part of MVN build and get the same issues in both places.  I haven't touched the VMArgs so they should be the same default ones in both cases?

Comment: Is the runtime environment (eg working directory, vm args, Caspian, system properties) otherwise identical? Is the server initialisation (ie path through the application) identical when running in both environments? Same config files? Same logging?

Comment: Can you please say exactly what you mean by "initialization phase takes 15 seconds". How did you time this? Which events did you to time it? What did you see on the screen? Is it "15 seconds before the JUnit runner view starts to display something" or "15 seconds before the process starts" or "..."?

Comment: I believe logging and everythign else is the same; I haven't explicitly changed everything and made sure to use the same configuration files at least.

Comment: I actually put a break point between the call that loads from config files and builds our memory model and the next call in configuration.  Then I used JVisualVM to get a trace of the CPU usage for just this one call by running it for just the time it took to go from first to second breakpoint.  This reading and building of config files is 95% roughly of the full bootup time judging from general system responsivness.  It seems to be the building of th model, not reading of files, that is taking up the CPU time.

Comment: Are you running Eclipse when you run your server standalone?  Eclipse consumes a sizable chunk of RAM.  It's possible your server is having to swap when running Eclipse and your server.  It also seems possible that the RAM allocated is different.  Can you add some debug statements after initialization to print the total number of GC's that have been run and the % of time that has been spent on GC?  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466878/can-you-get-basic-gc-stats-in-java) explains how.

Comment: I use eclipse to run both versions, just one I'm doing junit one I do the server alone.  I will try the other suggestion though.