# Store GC(Major/Minor/Full) timing in DB

Tags: java, performance

is it possible to store JAVA GC timings real time in DB.

Basically we are looking for some kind of event which is generated at the time of GC so we can alert our client about that.

Comment: You could poll the GarbageCollectorMBean every second or so.

Comment: Thanks for answer .if you have sample code then it would be highly appreciated

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466878/can-you-get-basic-gc-stats-in-java

Comment: Really thanks a lot. This is really helpful for me. I was checking GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo so i think there is process to get Notification as well. I am checking this i would share if found complete way to doing this

Comment: https://github.com/andrewliu100/SpringExample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/geekspearls/gc/GCMonitor.java. This show notification code.