# Determining GC type via GarbageCollectorMXBean

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jmx

I was reading [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/467366/5235665) on grabbing Java garbage collection activity info and noticed that the [`GarbageCollectorMXBean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html) doesn't have any data about what *type* of collection it was (Minor, Major, Full, etc.).

I'm wondering: is it possible to figure out (from Java code) whether a particular GC was minor, major or full?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing periodic GC stats from the GarbageCollectorMXBean's summary stats won't give you that type of information. If you are using Java 1.7+, you can subscribe to JMX notifications from each GarbageCollectorMXBean instance and you'll get a notification for every GC event which will give you a bit more detail on each individual event. The notification's UserData will contain an instance of the type [GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.html). The attribute [GcAction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.html#getGcAction()) will tell you if it was major or minor, and [GcCause](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.html#getGcCause()) will tell you the GC event cause.

Note that this references *com.sun* packages and assumes a HotSpot JVM. You can avoid referencing the com.sun packages in your code using pure JMX and OpenType inference, but be cautious about assuming this will work across all Java 1.7 JVMs.